# Firebase won't send authentication email

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to enable email authentication in my angular app that uses Firebase. Here is my code:

```
emailVerification(): any {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        user.sendEmailVerification(); 
        return true;
      });

}
```

afAuth is of type AngularFireAuth. While this function does return true, it does not send out an email. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Done, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, onAuthStateChanged could return a null reference if no user signed in. So what you should do in your handler is:

```
function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.sendEmailVerification(); 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also, before reaching out to firebase support, can you make sure the user is signed in at first place? For example, you can print the user object out and confirm no error message printed in dev console after send email verification. Otherwise, it could be something wrong with your code rather than a firebase issue.